# Select dependendes em php

Tags: php, html, html5, html-select

Estou inserindo informações em um formulário e preciso que meus selects fiquem dependentes. Neste caso, tenho dois selects, contendo informações de estado e a partir do estado selecionado, as informações de cidades irão aparecer no outro select. Como fazer?

```
<div id="info-geo">                  

<form name="novosDados" action="conexao.php" method="POST"> 

    <legend class="titulo" >Adicionar novo registro </legend> <br><br>

    <div class="w3-row-padding">

        <div class="w3-half">
          <label for="name">Estado</label>
          <select class="w3-select" name="estado">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um estado</option>
            <option value="BR">MG</option>
            <option value="EDE">SP</option>
            <option value="EVR">RJ</option>
          </select>                            
        </div>

        <div class="w3-half">
            <label for="name">Cidade</label>
            <select class="w3-select" name="cidade">

            <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha uma cidade</option>                                       
            <?php 
            if ($estado == 'MG'){ ?>
                <option value="BH">Belo Horizonte</option>
                <option value="Ipatinga">Ipatinga</option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>


            </select>                              
        </div>
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
</form>
```

Como pegar esse valor $estado, do meu primeiro select ?

Comment: Pelo o que você quer fazer, tem que selecionar um estado para buscar as cidades relacionadas? 

Faça um ajax que dispare uma requisição para um select pelo estado e preencha o outro select

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse repositório, ele simplifica esse trabalho https://gist.github.com/ografael/2037135

Comment: Como poderia implementar ?

Comment: Me da uns 10 minutos!

Comment: Melhor, vamos abrir um chat!! Fica melhor de conversar

Comment: Por mim pode ser

Comment: Acho que voce tem que abrir, vai aparecer uma opção enquanto vamos comentando

Comment: Como abrir o chat ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74159/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-alexsander-caproni).

Comment: Te mandei lá, ve se deu

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254739/ajuda-com-combo-box-com-ajax/254809#254809